# Wrong capitalisation in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, xetex

In German capitalisation is an essential feature of correct orthography, but my bibliography messes with it. Here is a near minimal WE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Load packages 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\begin{document}

Blabla\cite{Grassi}

\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{document}

\end{document}
```

Here's the full bibliography:

```
@misc{Grassi,
    author    = "Sergio Grassi",
    title     = "Chinas Agrarreform",
    year      = {2008},
    howpublished       = "\url{http://library.fes.de/pdf-files/bueros/china/05996.pdf}",
    note      = "[Online; accessed 31-July-2017]"
}
```

Bewilderingly, the following is produced, note Agrerreform:
[image]

Comment: No it is correct according to the bst you chose. Some bsts explicitly state that other than the first letter everything has to be lower case.

Comment: The `acm` bibliography style practices "sentence style", according to which only the first word of each sentence, plus certain proper nouns, acronyms, and given names, should be rendered in uppercase. Words in the `title` field that must not be converted to lowercase (say, because the document is not written in English) should be surrounded by curly braces. Thus, write either `title = "Chinas {Agrarreform}",` or `title     = "{Chinas Agrarreform}",`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks. It doesn't seem to hold for book though. This is displayed normally: @book{Diefenbach,     author    = "Thilo Diefenbach",     title     = "China abseits der Großstädte",     subtitle  = "Kurzgeschichten und Essays von Liu Jiming, Zhang Wei und Liu Qingbang",     year      = {2005},     publisher = "Europäischer Universitätsverlag",     address   = "Bochum" }

Comment: @Ludi - Sentence style of the `acm` bibliography style is practiced on the `title` field of most entry types, but not on that of type `@book`. My previous comment was directed at entries of type `@misc`, since that's what your code showed. (Sentence style isn't applied to the field `booktitle` either.) What exactly is your question? Are you complaining about some perceived inconsistency in the way the `acm` bibliography style applies sentence style?

Comment: @Mico I see! Your comments solved the problem, I was just surprised book behaved differently.